# Answering a user prompt from within NSIS installer

Tags: windows, batch-file, nsis

I have a batch file `install_license.bat` which installs licences for our software. The batch file simply runs a java class which does what is needed. And the batch file needs two parameters, action install and path to licence file which in turn are passed to the java class.

```
C:\MySoftware\install_license.bat install "D:\documents\myLicense.lic"
```

As part of our installer, we want to give an option to user to enter the path to licence. If user enters a path, above batch file should run as part of installation process and if not, then license installation should be skipped i.e. above batch should not run.

I know how to fire a batch from within installer.

However, the java program which actually installs the license gives a prompt to the user in the lines of:

```
Continue with license file installation? [y/N]
```

Based on user entering `yes` or `no`, the installation of license file continues. I do not have control over how this java class is working and I can not modify that.

Is there a way to handle this case from NSIS. That is, when running the batch, NSIS passes "y" to continue installation of the license file?

Here is the bat file:

```
@REM install_license.bat
@ECHO off

setlocal

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=

REM Gather all command line switches
:next_parm
IF [%1] == [] GOTO break_parm
    set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
        SHIFT /1
        GOTO next_parm
:break_parm

set LICENSE_PARAMETER=-Dinstalled.licenses.file="%INSTALLED_LICENSE_PATH%"

call "%_MY_JAVA%" %LICENSE_PARAMETER% -DCONSOLE_HOME=. -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml -cp %CLASSPATH% org.somepackage.MyClass %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
endlocal
```

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: when I did `echo y | C:\MySoftware\install_license.bat install "D:\documents\myLicense.lic"`... it treated it as N and exited telling "user has cancelled the operation"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a default result to most internal `cmd` commands and some external commands you simply need to echo the result and pipe it to the command:

```
echo y|call "%_MY_JAVA%" %LICENSE_PARAMETER% -DCONSOLE_HOME=. -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml -cp %CLASSPATH% org.somepackage.MyClass %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```